# How to move focus to the next row in Web Grid MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have an ASP .NET MVC application. In one of the views, which is a partial view, I have a Web Grid which is bound to the model.Two of the columns are editable in the grid. The user would like to navigate between the editable cells by pressing tab. The row needs to be saved when the user tabs out of the last editable column.

Here is my Web Grid

```
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow",
            rowsPerPage: ((Session["ShowAll"].ToString() == "true") ? 200 : 8),
            columnNames: new[] { "ID", "PathUse", "Design_No", "Prod_No", "Seq_No", "Seq_Position", "MCLSFlag", "Status" });
var shal = Session["ShowAll"].ToString();

     <div id="gridContent">

    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "LSgrid" },
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    columns: grid.Columns(

            grid.Column("ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>, style:"colID"),
            grid.Column("PathUse", header: "Image", format: @<img class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="180" src="@item.PathUse" />, style:"colPath"),
            grid.Column("DesignNo", header: "DesignNo", format: @<text>@item.Design_No</text>, style:"colDesignNo"),
            grid.Column("StyleNo", header: "StyleNo", format: @<text>@item.Prod_No</text>, style:"colStyleNo"),
            grid.Column("PageNo", header: "PageNo", format:@<input id="valPageNo" type="number" value="@item.Seq_No"/>, style:"colPageNo" ),
            grid.Column("Position", header: "Position", format:@<input id="valPosition" type="number" value="@item.Seq_Position" /> , style:"colPosition"),
            grid.Column("MCLSFlag", header: "MCLSFlag", format: @<input id="valMCLSFlag" type="checkbox" value="@item.MCLSFlag" />, style: "colMCLSFlag"),
            grid.Column("Status", header: "Status", format: @<text>@item.Status </text>, style: "colStatus"),
            grid.Column(header: "rNo", format: item => item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item) + 1, style:"colRowNo")
                     )
    )

</div>
```

Here is the script where I capture the keycode and save the row with a controller method

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.colPosition').on("keydown", function (e) {
           var eCode = e.keycode || e.which


           if (eCode == 9) {

               iid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colID').text();

               idesign = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colDesignNo').text();

               istyle = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colStyleNo').text();

               var ides1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('#valPageNo').val();

               var ipos1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('#valPosition').val();

               var irno = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colRowNo').text();

               $.ajax({
                   url: '@Url.Action("SaveLineSheetGirdRow", "LSControl")',
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false,
                   data: { id: iid, ipgNo: ides1, ipos: ipos1, bmcls: false, rownum:irno },
                   success: function (result) { refreshImageGrid(result);}
               }).done(function (result) {

                   console.log("saved");
                   return false;
               });
               function refreshImageGrid(result) {

                   $('#MainPage').html(result);
                   alert("After MainPage Load");
                   alert($(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition').val());
                   $(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition').focus();
               }
           }
   });
    });
```

This, however, does not work.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT ..
Following Stephen's suggestion, made the following changes to the event capture and callback functions. Getting Incorrect Type error in the callback portion where it is referring t o the row variable

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.colPosition').on("keydown", function (e) {
           var eCode = e.keycode || e.which

           //alert("this code .");
           if (eCode == 9) {
               //alert($(this).closest('tr').);
               // alert("position tab pressed");
               var row = $(this).closest('tr');
               alert(row.next().find('#valPosition').val())
               iid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colID').text();
            //   alert(iid);
               idesign = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colDesignNo').text();
            //   alert(idesign);
               istyle = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colStyleNo').text();
             //  alert(istyle);
               var ides1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('#valPageNo').val();
           //    alert(ides1);
               var ipos1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('#valPosition').val();

               var irno = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.colRowNo').text();
               alert(irno);
          //     var imcls = $(this).closest('tr').find('#colMCLSFlag').val();
               $.ajax({
                   url: '@Url.Action("SaveLineSheetGirdRow", "LSControl")',
                   type: 'POST',
                   cache: false,
                   data: { id: iid, ipgNo: ides1, ipos: ipos1, bmcls: false, rownum:irno },
                   success: function (result) { refreshImageGrid(result);}
               }).done(function (result) {

                   console.log("saved");
                   return false;
               });
               function refreshImageGrid(result,row) {
                  // alert("refresh");
                   $('#MainPage').html(result);
                   alert("After MainPage Load");
                   alert(row.next().find('#valPosition').val());
                   row.next().find('#valPosition').focus();
               }
           }
   });
    });
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting any errors. The focus doesnt go to the next row as expected.

Comment: You have shown a lot of code but not indicated at all where its failing. Is you ajax call working? Is it hitting the success callback? Do you enter the `refreshImageGrid` function? Debug your code and determine where the issue is! And inspect the value of `$(this)` inside that function - what are you expecting that to return?

Comment: If you have no clue, then let's narrow down. In your Internet browser, open inspection tool, put a break point in this line `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition').focus();`, when it hits the line go to console enter `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition')`, `$(this).closest('tr').next()`, `$(this).closest('tr')`, `this`. If it never hits the line, it means there's an error before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did look at the debug and Im getting 'undefined ' as the value for $(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition') .

Comment: It is hitting the Success callback and the alert I added is popping up correctly.

Comment: that's the problem

Comment: `$(this)` is not your element! You need to pass the element to your function

Comment: If you attach a click handler to a `td` then `this` is the `td` element who receives the event and it makes sense to do `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('#valPosition').focus();`  But in your case you can't use `this`, because the function is just a call back from Ajax and your code doesn't know which row needs to be updated.

Comment: Add `var row = $(this).closest('tr');` as the first line in your keydown function (and then use `refreshImageGrid(result, row);` to pass it to the function - function refreshImageGrid(result, row) {` and then `row.next().find('#valPosition').focus();` (and you can also use `var iid = row.find('td.colID').text();` etc. But you also have invalid html - `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: @derloopkat : Thanks - that makes sense. New to MVC and JQuery  :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks ill try your suggestion. I have a question though:

Comment: @StephenMuecke : would simply saying row.find('td.ColID')..find the row ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `var row = $(this).closest('tr');` means `row` is already the `<tr>` element. Are you wanting to find the `<td class="ColID">` element within the row?

Comment: I get the following error in console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at refreshImageGrid (LScontrol?filterData=LSBusinessObject.Filter:489)
    at Object.success (LScontrol?filterData=LSBusinessObject.Filter:479)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: It looks like the var row is not getting recognized as a webgrid row. Is there a way to cast ?

Comment: We cannot guess what code your using now!

Comment: I added the var row = $(this).closest('tr') and passed the row as a parameter to the call back. I cannot paste the code here as it is too long. Will re-post with the edit

Comment: Use `$(row).next().find('#valPosition').focus();`

Comment: $(row).next().find('#valPosition').focus() doesnt work either! I dont get any errors but the focus does not go to that column.